# Display result of SQL arithmetic

Tags: sql, math

I am fairly new to SQL. I have a table with several columns: item ID, purchased price and price sold. I need to write a sql statement to return the difference between the purchased price and price sold along with the item ID

Thanks!

Comment: `select [price sold] - [purchase price] as difference from...`

Comment: look here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp you could find answer for simple queris like this

Answer (score 1):

```
Select itemID, purchasePrice - soldPrice
from myTable;
```

This will return all ItemID's, and the difference in the prices for each.  You can add a where clause to filter.

Comment: Assuming you sold it for more than you purchased it, this would result in a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
declare @itemID varchar(55), @purchasePrice float, @salePrice float

    set @itemID = 'Shirt'
    set @purchasePrice = 65.50
    set @salePrice = 78.98

    select @itemID, @salePrice - @purchasePrice
```